# what is the difference between bash lua and source lua?

Tags: bash, shell, lua, git-bash

i want to run a lua script by 'bash', but the output isn't same as expected.

a shell script `bb.sh`

```bash
lua -e 'print "hha"'
echo $?
echo 'aaa' 
echo $?
( echo 'aaa' )
echo $?
echo $PATH
```

the output of 'bb.sh' run by 'bash' and 'source'

```bash
$ bash bb.sh
127      <---------------  why is os.exit(127) ?
aaa
0
aaa
0
/c/Users/lawsssscat/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/lawsssscat/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/cmd:/usr/bin:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Program Files (x86)/Tencent/微信web开发者工具/dll:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/c/Program Files/lua:/c/Program Files/luarocks:/c/MinGW/bin:/c/Ruby31-x64/bin:/c/Ruby24-x64/bin:/c/Users/lawsssscat/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Program Files/qemu:/c/Users/lawsssscat/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/lawsssscat/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Program Files/ffmpeg/bin:/e/nodejs/node_global:/c/Users/lawsssscat/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin:/c/Users/lawsssscat/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310:/c/Users/lawsssscat/Desktop/cmder:/c/cmake/bin:/c/bash_extend:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl


$ source bb.sh
hha      <--------------- the output i expect
0        <--------------- the output i expect
aaa
0
aaa
0
/c/Users/lawsssscat/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/lawsssscat/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/cmd:/usr/bin:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Program Files (x86)/Tencent/微信web开发者工具/dll:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/c/Program Files/lua:/c/Program Files/luarocks:/c/MinGW/bin:/c/Ruby31-x64/bin:/c/Ruby24-x64/bin:/c/Users/lawsssscat/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Program Files/qemu:/c/Users/lawsssscat/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/lawsssscat/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Program Files/ffmpeg/bin:/e/nodejs/node_global:/c/Users/lawsssscat/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin:/c/Users/lawsssscat/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310:/c/Users/lawsssscat/Desktop/cmder:/c/cmake/bin:/c/bash_extend:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

why is os.exit(127) and run't 'print "hha"' in lua when the script run by 'bash'?

(win10 system git bash)

and i print $PATH above，they are same.

```
$ type -a lua
lua is aliased to `lua53'
lua is /usr/local/bin/lua
lua is /c/Program Files/lua/lua
```

Finally, I found out that :

i have maken a setting that "cmd" run `doskey lua=lua53 $*` command when it be open. now i remove above command, and "bash lua" results return to normal, t but i don't know why.

Comment: Where is the lua executable? Try `type -a lua` in both your interactive shell and in the script.

Comment: thanks. it should be caused by  `alias`

Comment: "lua is /c/Program Files/lua/lua" - this looks pretty darn wrong to me, considering this seems to be on Unix

Comment: i have maken a setting that "cmd" run `rem doskey lua=lua53 $*` command when it be open. now i remove above command, and "bash lua" results return to normal, t but i don't know why.  